# How to use javac on booted Debian?

Tags: windows, debian, javac

Say, I want to use `javac` command in Debian, which is my second OS installed parallely with Win7. Windows has got the newest ver of jdk and jre, and also they are added to system variables. How can I refer to java compiler from the level of Debian?

Answer (score 0):

it depends on how you installed java. you can use update-alternatives to specify the existence of javadoc, or create a symlink of javadoc by hand to /usr/bin anyway my advice is to use this repo to install java

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu precise main
```

though it sais ubuntu precise im using debian 8 myself so dont be scared to put that that way.

another less elegant way is to use the source command, to tell bash where to find javadoc